# How to call own settings from MySQL in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, settings, config

I am building project based on CodeIgniter 3.
My first idea was to store user settings in additional config file and call ex. `$this->config->item('item_name')`.
However I need not only read those settings but to save them.
So my cuurent idea is to build additional tab_settings and store all my config values as 1 row.

The question is how to call those settings in CodeIgniter controllers/views.
Do I need to make SQL Query in every controller, or is it a way to do it one time only?

Or maybe is better idea for storing user settings in CI?

Answer (score 2):

You can save config settings in CI using:

```
$this->config->set_item('item_name', 'item_value');
```

Depending on what kind of setting your saving and how many there are, you may be better off with using the DB. If the settings are independent of each user, I would include the DB code in your user model, then when your user logs in, store their setting in the session to avoid excess DB calls. Otherwise create a separate model for the settings. You should not be interacting with the DB directly within a controller or view, always in a model.

Comment: Hi ChrisD, thx. I know that I need model then controller and view. Set_item is actually not saving the config permanently but setting only. The questios is do I need to call my setting controller/model every time I want to read/save setting in every other controller, or is it a way to read the DB settings and store them as a config in just one DB query.